# How to compare each item in list against previous item in Python

Tags: python, compare, output, paramiko

```
import paramiko
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect('hostname', username='test1234', password='test')
path = ['/home/test/', '/home/test1/','/home/test3/']
sftp = client.open_sftp()
for filename in sftp.listdir(path):
    stdin,stdout,stderr = client.exec_command('ls -1 %s' %filename)
    output = stdout.read().decode().splitlines()
    print output
```

I have multiple path and passing one by one to stdin to execute
command. While parsing first path, stdout is stored in output. Similar
wise while parsing second path. Second path output needs to be
compared with first path output and unique output needs to be stored.
I am not sure how to progress.

Comment: *"compare"* is pretty vague.

Comment: Use `==` to compare strings for equality ;-)

Comment: but i have nearly 30 outputs for each path then how can i use == to compare

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remember an output from previous iteration in a variable and compare:

```
prev_output = None
for filename in sftp.listdir(path):
    stdin,stdout,stderr = client.exec_command('ls -1 %s' %filename)
    output = stdout.read().decode().splitlines()
    print output
    if prev_output:
        if prev_output == output:
            print "Same"
        else:
            print "Different"
    prev_output = output
```